# Confused about how to use Selenium to perform integration testing on Asp.Net MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selenium-webdriver, xunit

I'm learning how to use Selenium to perform integration testing on my Asp.Net MVC web app but  I'm not sure I'm going about it in the best way. The Solution has two projects: the MVC app and the xUnit Test app. So far I have my tests using a class fixture to run all the tests in one context because first I need to log in, navigate to a certain page, and perform a multi-step action, which I can't do if the app is restarting for every test.

By default the test opens an instance of Chrome running in debug mode from the .exe and you end up on the login page. Because of this I'm running all my tests in a particular order using FindElements to identify inputs and operating it like a user. -> Login and make sure the LiveChat widget is there. -> Click a link and make sure the Url is correct -> Fill out a form and make sure the expected result is returned. etc.

I keep reading that it's usually bad practice to perform multiple tests with the same context but as far as I can tell that doesn't make sense in the context of UI testing of a website with authentication. I researched ways to run selenium tests on a currently-running instance of of Chrome so I could  start the project, log in, then run the tests. I found some articles, all using different methods, that seemed to confirm this possibility by running the chrome.exe from the CLI in debug mode and running the tests from another CLI instance (because the Text Explorer in Visual Studio is greyed out when the application is running...). Also by adding this line before instantiating the driver with ChromeOptions:

```
options.DebuggerAddress = "127.0.0.1:44330";

options.AddLocalStatePreference("browser", new { 
      enabled_labs_experiments = new string[] { 
          "http-auth-committed-interstitials@2" 
      } 
});

driver = new ChromeDriver("PATH\TO\CHROME.EXE", options);
```

This causes an error:

```
The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: WebDriverFixture fixture 

invalid argument: entry 0 of 'firstMatch' is invalid
from invalid argument: cannot parse capability: goog:chromeOptions
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Am I going about using Selenium in the totally wrong way by running all the tests in a particular order on one context? If so, what's the alternative? Thanks!